# Why can't I call function with get request on click?

Tags: jquery

Is this a browser quirk, or am I using get incorrectly? I read through the api docs, but wasn't able to find information on why I wouldn't be able to use it this way. I can copy and paste the link into my browser and it returns a different quote every time.

Right now, when I call this function, and it calls itself again, it will infinitely print out the same quote over and over, instead of generating a new quote.

```
function apiCall() {
  $.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1', function(data) {
    if (data[0].content.length > 100) {
      apiCall();
    }

    console.log(data[0].content);
  })

}
```

Comment: I had to clear the cache before I got a different quote. Just refreshing the page would return the same one.

Comment: I refreshed the page and was able to return a different one, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ajax get method to turn off cache:-

```
$.ajax({
  url: "'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    if (data[0].content.length > 100) {
      apiCall();
    }
    console.log(data[0].content);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I am still confused about why I could refresh the page and successfully get a new quote, but not when I called the get function within my code.

Comment: because `$.get` uses `$.ajax` with `cache: true`. that means if the same call is made, it doesn't make the actual call and calls the success with the previously returned data. until you refresh, which it will then make the first call again.